# IdentityServer3 Logout not Redirecting to origin

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver3, openid-connect, thinktecture-ident-server

I have MVC logging out from identityserver however it does not redirect automatically. I don't even get the "Click here to go back" that is usually displayed by default.

Here is my setup.

in the idsvr:
Factory is Aspnet identity using EF (mostly out of the box implementation)

```
IdentityServerOptions {
AuthenticationOptions =
    {
        EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true,
        SignInMessageThreshold = 3,
        EnableSignOutPrompt = false
    }
}
```

in MVC

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication (new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:port",
RedirectUri = "https://localhost:port",
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
{
SecurityTokenValidated = HereIGetRefreshTokenEtc(),
RedirectToIdentityProvider =  n =>
{
    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
    {
        var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");
        if (idTokenHint != null)
        {
            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
        }
    }
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
}
});
```

The Logout Controller action is like so

```
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        //Option 1 : because I have already provided redirect URI in initial configuration
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();

        //Option 2: Because option 1 did not work
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "https://mymvc.site" });

        //none of the return statements work. (obviously i have tried them individually)

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new{ area = ""});
        return Redirect("https://idsvr/connect/endsession");
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!
I was missing to add the link in the PostLogoutRedirectUris in the Client configuration. It was falling over saying "Invalid post logout URI".